# Inserting data into a database from forms

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to take data which has been typed into input boxes and then save them back to my database. I am connecting to a dataset called password with a table called password. This is my connection

```
passTableAdapters.passwordsTableAdapter pass = new passwordTableAdapters.passwordTableAdapter();
password.passwordsDataTable passtable = pass.GetData();
```

This allows me to connect to the dataset but from there I am really stuck. I want to take the information from the textbox and then save them back to the dataset.

I have been using [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233812%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) but still no luck. If someone can show me how to write back to the dataset I would be very grateful.

Comment: put your code for better response..

Comment: This is all the code I have, I don't know where to start. I have my connection and that is it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the data from your `HTML Controls` you may try this logic. I am assuming that you have Two Control like

**HTML:**

```
<input id="username" name="username" type="text" />
<input id="password" name="password" type="password" />
```

**Code Behind:**

```
var username = Request.Form["username"];
var password = Request.Form["password"];
```

**Note:**

> Never forget to Give the inputs a name as well as an id otherwise `Request.Form` will not work

By using this you may get the value from input tag and then pass these values to your function as a parameter in which you are using `Insert Query`.

Hope you understand.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how do I then send these back to the dataset though? I can call pass.Update() but don't i need to insert these into a row?

Comment: you have created your own `update` function or you are using inbuilt `update` function.

Comment: Built in. I am using the wizard for creating the datasets

Comment: check that inbuilt `update` function is taking some parameter or object in it.Means `update` function is parameterized or not.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using type data adapters for accessing the database. If this is the case you should have insert methods. If not you need to reconfigure this and tell XDS to generate those methods for you.

[image: TableAdapter Configuration Wizard]

Retrieving data from your form is as easy as TextBoxName.Text  .